# Cross Browser issues with Center Align

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding, and I am having problems making the page appear correctly on all browsers. Right now it works perfectly with IE, but I lose formatting when I open in in Firefox or Chrome.

This is an excerpt of the code I'm using:

```
 <style type="text/css">

#headerIMG {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    width:100%;
    }
label {
    padding-right:10px;
    text-align:left;
    {
table   {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    align: center;
    }

.centerspacer {
    width:50%;
    }
tr  {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0 px;
    }

td {
    padding:5px;
    }
.center {
    text-align:center;
    }
.button {
    float:none;
    display:block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align:center;
    }

form    {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
.rectbcontent {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    }
table.tbody {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>

 <form action="https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="00DK0000005Iu4O">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.vela-ins.com">


<table class="tbody">

<tr>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
<td><label  for="first_name">First Name</label></td>
<td><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" />          </td>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td><label  for="last_name">Last Name</label></td>
<td><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td><label  for="email">Email</label></td>
<td><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td><label  for="phone">Phone</label></td>
<td><input  id="phone" maxlength="15" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
</tr>

 <tr>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td><label  for="company">Company</label></td>
<td><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="centerspacer"></td><td>
<label  for="city">City</label></td>
<td><input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td><label  for="state">State/Province</label></td><td><input  id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" /></td><td class="centerspacer"></td>
</tr>

 </table>
</select>
</form>


 <script>
var x = 'https://images.wrberkley.com/imageserver/WRBTS/VELA/site/images/';

var assignrule;
var imageURL;
var lob = getQueryVariable('product');

lob = lob.toLowerCase().charAt(0);



switch (lob)
{
//change this case to look at first character for construction
case 'c':

imageURL=x + 'Headlines/constructionheader.png';

assignrule='Construction';
break;


case 'm':
imageURL=x + 'Headlines/manufacturingheader.png';

assignrule="Manufacturing";
break;
case 'p': 
imageURL=x + 'Headlines/professionalliabilityheader.png';
assignrule="Professional Liability";
break;
case 'g':
imageURL=x + 'Headlines/generalcasualtyheader.png';
assignrule="General Casualty";
break;
default:
imageURL=x + 'header.png';
assignrule="default";
}
document.getElementById('headerIMG').src = imageURL
document.getElementById("00NK0000000Yqv2").value = assignrule;
</script>
```

Comment: I've been coding for about a week, so I'm sure there are plenty of errors in here. Sorry!

Comment: Yes. Please tell us which error you are asking about. Which code piece exactly does not work as expected? Please put only the relevant code in the question, and use the whole code for a demo (on your domain, jsfiddle, jsbin or wherever) only.

Answer (score 1):

To center the table, remove those `centerspacer` cells from the markup, and use only

```
table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Besides, you have a syntax error in your css declaration for `label`, which will crash any following styles. Check your browser's error console!

Answer (score 0):

For relatively positioned elements:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

For everything else:

http://jqueryui.com/position/